Pdf to Blob for Firebase Storage
I am trying to convert a PDF to a Blob so I can upload it to Firebase Storage. Although I can see the uploaded PDF in the Firebase console, I cannot open it. I get the error: "Failed to load PDF file."
This is the conversion function:
const uriToBlob = async (uri) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch resource');
      }
      const blob = await response.blob();
      return blob;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };


And I perform the conversion this way:

    export const uploadFile = async (fileUri, filename, course, isPublic) => {
        const userCredentials = getCredentials();
        if (!userCredentials) {
            console.error('User credentials not found');
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            const fileBlob = await uriToBlob(fileUri);
            console.log('Blob size:', fileBlob.size);
        
            const storage = getStorage();
            const storageRef = ref(storage, 'notes/' + filename);
        
            const metadata = {
                contentType: 'application/pdf'
            };
        
            const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, fileBlob, metadata);
        
            const fileUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
            console.log('File URL:', fileUrl);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        }

        // Get current user ID
        const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;

        // Add file metadata to Firestore
        const notesCollectionRef = collection(firestoreInstance, 'notes/');
        await addDoc(notesCollectionRef, {
            filename: filename,
            university: userCredentials?.university || '', // Ensure university field is not undefined
            department: userCredentials?.department || '',
            course: course,
            contentType: 'application/pdf',
            isPublic: isPublic,
            userId: userId,
            url: fileUrl, // Store download URL in Firestore
        });

        console.log('File uploaded successfully');
    
};

and call the function this way
uploadFile('Result.pdf','result','Algs',true);

Try this:
const uriToBlob = async (uri) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch resource, status: ' + response.status);
        }
        console.log('Content-Type:', response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
        const blob = await response.blob();
        console.log('Blob type:', blob.type);
        console.log('Blob size:', blob.size);
        return blob;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

And This:
const userCredentials = getCredentials();
if (!userCredentials) {
    console.error('User credentials not found');
    return;
}

try {
    const fileBlob = await uriToBlob(fileUri);
    console.log('Blob size:', fileBlob.size);

    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'notes/' + filename);

    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'application/pdf'
    };

    const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, fileBlob, metadata);

    const fileUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    console.log('File URL:', fileUrl);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
}

And check all of the values in the console to make sure all of the values are correct and the Blob type is application/pdf

When i click on the URL the file can not be opened. But the Blob is 1240 in size

I have updated my answer please make sure you are actually passing PDF. It would be helpful to see your Input/Output and desired Input/Output

i edited my question to provide more info
